# Recovering original matrix from its kernel matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

For a given linear kernel matrix, $K [n \times n]$,  we would like to recover the original matrix $X$.

In general it is not possible to recover the data matrix from a kernel matrix, as the projection of data matrix into possibly infinite-dimensional space loses the original embedding. However, we impose the condition on the original matrix $X$ to be some perturbation of a known matrix $M [n \times p]$ measured in terms of the Frobenius norm.

For the simple case, where the kernel function is linear, the problem can be expressed as the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{X}{\text{min}}
& & \|X - M \|_F^2 \\
&\text{subject to}& & XX^{\top} = K\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where, $K$ and $M$ are known.

1. How would you solve the above problem? Is there an analytical solution to this?
2. For a general (known or unknown) kernel function which satisfies Mercer's condition, is it possible to retrieve the original matrix?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes. well, strictly speaking, $K$  is positive semi-definite.

Comment: I think so. If I recall correctly, by definition, a p.s.d matrix is symmetric and invertible.

Comment: A p.d. matrix is invertible. Not a p.s.d.

Comment: If we restrict ourselves to a positive-definite matrix $K$, would it help?

Comment: $X [n \times p]$ and $p \gg n$, so it's a fat matrix.

Comment: hmm..., I think it is safe to assume $X$ has full row rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following optimization problem in fat matrix $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X - \mathrm M \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \mathrm X^\top = \mathrm K\end{array}$$

where fat matrix $\mathrm M \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$ and symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $\mathrm K \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ are given. Since the objective function is

$$\begin{array}{rl} \| \mathrm X - \mathrm M \|_{\text{F}}^2 &= \mbox{tr} \left( (\mathrm X - \mathrm M) (\mathrm X - \mathrm M)^\top \right)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm X \mathrm X^\top - \mathrm X \mathrm M^\top - \mathrm M \mathrm X^\top + \mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm K \right) - \langle \mathrm M , \mathrm X \rangle - \langle \mathrm X , \mathrm M \rangle + \| \mathrm M \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm K \right) - 2 \langle \mathrm M , \mathrm X \rangle + \| \mathrm M \|_{\text{F}}^2\end{array}$$

the original optimization problem can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle \mathrm M , \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \mathrm X^\top = \mathrm K\end{array}$$

Let the Lagrangian be

$$\mathcal L (\mathrm X, \Lambda) := \langle \mathrm M , \mathrm X \rangle - \frac 12 \langle \Lambda , \mathrm X \mathrm X^\top - \mathrm K \rangle$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain two matrix equations

$$\begin{array}{rl} \left(\dfrac{\Lambda + \Lambda^\top}{2}\right) \mathrm X &= \mathrm M\\ \mathrm X \mathrm X^\top &= \mathrm K \end{array}$$

Let us introduce (symmetric) matrix variable $\mathrm S := \dfrac{\Lambda + \Lambda^\top}{2}$. We write

$$\begin{array}{rl} \mathrm S \mathrm X &= \mathrm M\\ \mathrm X \mathrm X^\top &= \mathrm K \end{array}$$

and, thus,

$$\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top = \mathrm S \,\mathrm X \mathrm X^\top \mathrm S = \mathrm S \mathrm K \mathrm S = \mathrm S \mathrm K^{\frac 12} \mathrm K^{\frac 12} \mathrm S$$

Hence, we obtain the matrix equation

$$\mathrm S \mathrm K^{\frac 12} = \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{\frac 12}$$

Assuming that $\rm K$ is **positive definite**,

$$\mathrm S = \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{\frac 12} \mathrm K^{-\frac 12}$$

Assuming that $\rm M$ has **full row rank** (so that $\rm \mathrm M \mathrm M^\top$ is invertible),

$$\mathrm S^{-1} = \mathrm K^{\frac 12} \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{-\frac 12}$$

and, thus, the optimal solution is

$$\boxed{\bar{\mathrm X} := \mathrm S^{-1} \mathrm M = \color{blue}{\mathrm K^{\frac 12} \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{-\frac 12} \mathrm M}}$$

Verifying that the constraint is satisfied,

$$\bar{\mathrm X} \bar{\mathrm X}^\top = \mathrm K^{\frac 12} \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{-\frac 12} \mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{-\frac 12} \mathrm K^{\frac 12} = \mathrm K$$

Lastly, the minimum is

$$\mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm K \right) - 2 \langle \mathrm M , \bar{\mathrm X} \rangle + \| \mathrm M \|_{\text{F}}^2 = \| \mathrm K^{\frac 12} - \left( \,\mathrm M \mathrm M^\top \right)^{\frac 12} \|_{\text{F}}^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort. I really appreciate it.

Comment: 1) My first question concerns generalizeability for other kernel functions $k$'s that meet the Mercer's condition, and hence their corresponding Kernel matrix form, where $K^{\prime}_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$. Examples could be the polynomial kernel or RBF?

Comment: 2) Could you use the semi-definite relaxation of qcqp to solve the problem where the original problem is specified as:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \left\| X - M \right\|_F^2 \\
\text{subject to} & 0 \preceq  K^{\prime} \preceq K
\end{array}
$$
where, $K$ and $M$ are given with the former a p.s.d., and $K^{\prime}_{i,j} = k(x_i, x_j)$